# Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Charles Babbage?

Tags: museums, england, geek-travel, science

I'm travelling to the UK from Australia and wanted to visit a number of sites of scientific history.

One at the top of my list is [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage).

I understand there is the [Totnes Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totnes_Museum) in [Devon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devon). There appeared to be a [question about his birthplace](http://www.devonperspectives.co.uk/babbage.html).

It looks like there is [a display](http://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/visitmuseum/plan_your_visit/exhibitions/computing) at the [Science Museum in London](http://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/) about [his life](http://collection.sciencemuseum.org.uk/people/cp36993/charles-babbage).

But can you visit a museum with a display about his life and works?

My question is: **Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Charles Babbage?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regard to sites devoted to Charles Babbage, he has been awarded a blue plaque in London which you can visit at 1 Dorset Street (more info: http://openplaques.org/plaques/3061) at the house where he lived for 40 years. This is though just the plaque, the house its self is not open to the general public and there isn't an information board.

I don't belive there are any museums devoted entirely to him in the UK: I quickly searched through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_museums_in_the_United_Kingdom) list and didn't notice anything obvious. The Science Museum in London appears to be your best bet and you are already aware of it: according to [Atlas Obscura](http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/difference-engine-2) they have a working difference engine and a section of his brain. There is also the [Center for computing history](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/) in Cambridge and the [Bletchley park](https://bletchleypark.org.uk/) museam near Milton Keynes.